Non-standard model of arithmetic
In Leary & Kristiansen I was reading about how the compactness theorem can by used to show there are non-standard models of arithmetic. The example was that if $\Sigma$ is a set of $\mathcal L_{NT}$-sentences (number theory), let $\Theta$ be a new collection of sentences in the language $\mathcal L=\mathcal L_{NT}\cup\{c\}$ where $c$ is a new constant symbol, then $$\Theta:=\Sigma\cup\{0<c,S0<c,SS0<c,SSS0<c,\dots\}$$
The compactness theorem is used to show $\Theta$ has a model $\mathfrak A'$. They then point out that $\mathfrak A=\mathfrak A'\upharpoonright_{\mathcal L_{NT}}$ is a model for $\Sigma$, but I have trouble understanding what $\mathfrak A$ is, and how it is different from the standard model $\mathfrak R$ after the restriction. They say $\mathfrak A$ is like $\mathfrak A'$ exept you "forget about the interpretation of the constant symbol $c$", what does this mean formally? And what happens so to speak with the sentences $SS\cdots S0<c$ after the restriction (after we have "forgotten" the interpretation of $c$)?

It means you only allow formulae that don't use the new constant symbol $c$.  Whichever element mapped to $c$ in your model witnesses the existence of an element that is larger than any standard natural number.  That's still true even though you can't express this concept (without using $c$) as a set of first-order sentences.

The official name for this is the reduct. You take the structure $\mathfrak A'$ and make a structure $\mathfrak A$ in signature $\mathcal L_{NT}$ by using the same underlying set as $\mathfrak A'$ and and the same interpretations of all the symbols except $c.$ You don't need to worry any further, as $c$ is not in the signature $\mathcal L_{NT}$, so you're not required or supposed to interpret it in $\mathfrak A$.
The sentences $c > S^n0$ are not $\mathcal L_{NT}$ sentences, so they aren't interpreted by $\mathfrak A.$ However, there is still an element $a\in A$ ($A$ is the underlying set of both $\mathfrak A$ and $\mathfrak A'$) such that $a = c ^{\mathfrak A'}$ (i.e. it is what we were interpreting $c$ as in $\mathfrak A'$), and we have $\mathfrak A\models a > S^n0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, since $<$, $0$, and $S$ are interpreted the same.

Thank you very much for the answer. This is how i understand it now, pleace correct me: Would it be correct that $\mathfrak A$ is the structure $(\mathbb{N},c,+,\cdot,E,S)$, just that it doesn't make sense to write $c^\mathfrak A$, since the symbol $c$ is not interpreted and just left untouched by $\mathfrak A$. But then, as you say, we still have that $c^{\mathfrak A'}=a\in\mathbb{N}$. So, since all we did when we went from $\mathfrak A'$ to $\mathfrak A$ was to reduce the language, no changes have occured regarding what is true and what is not...

...And therefore since the interpretation of $S^n0<c$ was $n<a$ in $\mathfrak A$ (for all $n$), the claim $n<a$ is still regarded as true by $\mathfrak A$. But regarding expressibility, in $\mathfrak A$ we could never actually find a $S^m0$ such that its interpretation would correspond to $a$. And thus we have something that is both true ($n<a$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$) and inexpressible in a $\mathcal L_{NT}$-structure.

@Haa I wouldn't write it $(\mathbb N, c,+,\cdot, E, S)$. First, I wouldn't write the underlying set as $\mathbb N$, though it technically could be if the structure were countable (but then $+$ and $\cdot$ would have a much different meaning from the usual one), but I see no indication it's even countable here. I used $A$ to denote the underlying set. Second, $c$ shouldn't be there... that constant is not in the signature... but looking at how Leary and Kristianson write the signature of arithmetic, that's where 0 goes anyway. I'd write $(A,0^{\mathfrak A'}, +^{\mathfrak A'},\ldots).$

@Haa which emphasises that the interpretations are the same as from $\mathfrak A' = (A, 0^{\mathfrak A'},\ldots, S^{\mathfrak A}, c^{\mathfrak A'})$. Most of the rest of what you say is right. I am a bit unsure what you mean by your last comment. If you mean something like "there was an "infinite" element definable in $\mathfrak A'$ (by the formula $x = c$), but there's no longer any infinite element definable in $\mathfrak A$, although they do exist there", than that's right (or at least it's unclear that there's such a definable element... it is right that there isn't, but requires proof).
